# In dictionary key value pair, how to unwrap value, where value can be different sorts of types, to String

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, eureka-forms

Eureka form values return optional values so I want to iterate in each value and unwrap them. However, these values consist of Double, Int, String. How do I unwrap them to String?

```
    let wrapped = self.formValues()

    var unwrapped = [String:Any]()

    for (k,v) in wrapped {
        unwrapped[k] = v as! String ?? ""
    }
    return unwrapped
```

I get this error:

```
    Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Double' (0x7fff879c1a10) to 'Swift.String' (0x7fff879c41c8).
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have values of type Double, Int and String, but they are all optional, I want to unwrap them all to String

Comment: Given the deleted answers and the comments to them it’s really hard to understand what you really want here. Care to elaborate or perhaps the question should be closed/removed?

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson how do I remove this? The formValues is returning optional values, since it's a [String:Any] I could not use ! to unwrap the value so I initially wanted to unwrap them by casting them into String. What I wanted to happen was to get unwrapped values which I thought can be done by casting them into String. But I was able to unwrap them with ! by casting formValues into [String :Any?]. let wrapped = self.formValues() turned to let wrapped = self.formValues() as [String:Any?] and unwrapped[k] = v as! String ?? "" turned to unwrapped[k] = v! ?? nil.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
v as! String ?? ""
```

with

```
String(v)
```

Comment: i tried it but i get this error -> Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible' because only concrete types can conform to protocols

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want,
But i think you are trying to cast [String: Any?] to [String: Any]

```swift
  let unwrapped: [String: Any] = wrapped.mapValues { $0 ?? "" }
```

Or

```swift
   let unwrapped: [String: String] = wrapped.mapValues { (value) -> String in
    guard let value = value as? LosslessStringConvertible  else {
        return ""
    }
    return "\(value)"
}
```